# TCPDF generates an ugly image for an A3 page size paper

Tags: php, image, pdf, tcpdf

Trying to generate an A3 sized PDF using TCPDF while adding an Image as a **background image** (3693x5136 px saved as CMYK) plus some text, I use this code:

```
$this->pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, -1, true);
$this->pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$this->pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$this->pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$this->pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
$this->pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);    
$this->pdf->AddPage('P', 'A3');
$this->pdf->setJPEGQuality(99);
$this->pdf->setImageScale(1);
$this->pdf->Image('path/img/a3bg.jpg', 0, 0, 297, 420, 'JPEG', '', '', FALSE, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$this->pdf->endPage();
$this->pdf->setPageMark();
$this->pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'F');
```

The background image looks strange when opened in Reader/Photoshop (left) and looks alright when preview with Firefox or Chrome (right). Why is that?

Comment: what happens if you convert that jpg to RGB?

Comment: @MarcB: If I use RGB everything looks OK; my printer guy told me to always use CMYK images when doing PDF. The tool I build generates PDFs for a printing house, they will never be printed inhouse. It's just the preview that bugs me. Users will want to preview the PDFs before sending them to the printing house.